# Why C function returning struct attribute returns 0 after first loop iteration?

Tags: c, function, for-loop, struct

So I am quite knew to C so forgive me if this is a obvious question. I can't work out why in the `selectedNode` function returns a correct value the first time but 0 for all others. It is being accessed from inside a struct by the length attribute. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct { int x; int y; } VECTOR;
typedef struct { VECTOR nodes[8]; int length; } NODE_LIST;

VECTOR Deltas[8] = {{-2, 1}, {-2,-1}, {-1,-2}, { 1,-2},
                    { 2,-1}, { 2, 1}, { 1, 2}, {-1, 2}};

NODE_LIST NodeSuccessors(VECTOR node)
{
    NODE_LIST successors;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i; i < 8; i++)
    {
        VECTOR N = {node.x + Deltas[i].x, node.y + Deltas[i].y};
        if ((N.x <  8) && (N.y <  8) && (N.x >= 0) && (N.y >= 0))
        {
            successors.nodes[count] = N;
            count++;
        }
    }
    successors.length = count;
    return successors;
}

int SelectedNode(NODE_LIST nodelist)
{
    int bestNode = 8; // the most a node could have.
    int len = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < nodelist.length; n++)
    {
        len = NodeSuccessors(nodelist.nodes[n]).length;
        printf("%d, ", len);
        if (len < bestNode)
        {
            bestNode = len;
        }
    }
    return bestNode;
}

int main()
{
    VECTOR node = {4,4};
    NODE_LIST nNodes = NodeSuccessors(node);

    int best = SelectedNode(nNodes);
    printf("\nresult: %d\n", best);
}
```

The current resulting output is:

```
8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, result: 0
```

Cheers.

Comment: this `for (int i; i < 8; i++)` --> `for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)`

Comment: Turn up your compiler warning level, it should have emitted a warning about using an uninitialized variable.

Comment: ahhh cheers yeah that did it. As if that didn't come up as a warning.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Strangely, I did not get a warning on the OP's code either on Windows using MinGW 4.9.2 or on CentOS Linux using gcc 4.8.5. I used -Wall and -Wextra.

Comment: ... doing debug builds. I do get the warning building a release build. Weird.

Comment: @FredLarson That is odd. I just tested this code on gcc.godbolt.org and saw the same behavior you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your for loop you have an uninitialised value `i`. The uninitialised value contains garbage.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
```

If you have turn on a compiler option for your compiler it would have warned you. Example with `gcc -Wall -Werror`

> error: variable 'i' is uninitialized when used here
>   [-Werror,-Wuninitialized]
>
> ```
> for (int i; i < 8; i++)
>          ^
> ```